# Unable to extract data from Soap response

Tags: php, soap, xpath, domxpath

This is the code im using:

```
$doc = // SOAP Response
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
            $xpath->registerNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
            $xpath->registerNamespace('api', 'http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API');

// Response:
            if ($xpath->query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/api:get_cdrsResponse')->length < 1)
            {
                throw new EnswitchResponseFaultException();
            }
```

it keeps throwing this exception what am I doing wrong?

This is the response im getting ([Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/PLtMWQmg)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><get_cdrsResponse 
    xmlns="http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API">
<s-gensym3>
<scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
<recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
<outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</outgroup_name>
<bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid</bill_type>
</s-gensym3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introduction**

Not sure where you got `$xpath->registerNamespace('api', 'http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API');` but is not a valid `namespace` go get all valid namespace you can use

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($sxe->getDocNamespaces(true));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    [soapenc] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
    [xsd] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    [soap] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
    [] => http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API
)
```

**You XML from [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/PLtMWQmg)**

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><get_cdrsResponse 
    xmlns="http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API">
<s-gensym3>
<scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
<recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
<outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</outgroup_name>
<bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid</bill_type>
</s-gensym3>
</get_cdrsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

**Solution**

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace("api", "http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API");
$path = $sxe->xpath("//api:s-gensym3");
$info = array_shift($path);

if (!$info)
    throw new Exception("Invalid Response");

echo $info->scustomer, PHP_EOL;
echo $info->recording, PHP_EOL;
echo $info->outgroup_name, PHP_EOL;
echo $info->bill_type, PHP_EOL;
```

**[Output](http://eval.in/13018)**

```
4458

abc
prepaid
```

[See Live DEMO](http://eval.in/13018)

======================================

### UPDATE

======================================

When dealing with multiple children you can just ignore namespace  and use [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)

Example

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <get_cdrsResponse xmlns="http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API">
            <s-gensym3>
                <scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
                <recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</outgroup_name>
                <bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid14</bill_type>
            </s-gensym3>
            <s-gensym5>
                <scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
                <recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abcd</outgroup_name>
                <bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid</bill_type>
            </s-gensym5>
            <s-gensym7>
                <scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
                <recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abce</outgroup_name>
                <bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid13</bill_type>
            </s-gensym7>
            <s-gensym11>
                <scustomer xsi:type="xsd:string">4458</scustomer>
                <recording xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <outgroup_name xsi:type="xsd:string">abcf</outgroup_name>
                <bill_type xsi:type="xsd:string">prepaid12</bill_type>
            </s-gensym11>
        </get_cdrsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$response = $sxe->children('soap', true)->Body->children()->get_cdrsResponse;

foreach ( $response->children() as $gensym ) {
    echo $gensym->scustomer, PHP_EOL;
    echo $gensym->recording, PHP_EOL;
    echo $gensym->outgroup_name, PHP_EOL;
    echo $gensym->bill_type, PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Looks like its working but what if I've got multiple s-gensym ? for example `s-gensym3`, `s-gensym5`,`s-gensym7`.
How can I loop them all ? like that: this aint working: `foreach ($xpath->query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/api:get_cdrsResponse/*[string(api:server)='.$this->escapeXPathString($server).'][string(api:callid)='.$this->escapeXPathString($callid).']') as $cdr)`

Comment: @DanRevah your question does not contain that information .... ??? If my code has worked then i guess have answered the question .. You should at least say thanks  ... If you have any other request please update your question and indicate its an update

Comment: well thanks for first, and secondly thats where I was stuck and I saw you solved that problem so I thought it would be easy to solve this issue for you too.

Comment: add the full `xml` to pastbin let me see

Comment: You `xml` is wrong .. but i would update answer with corrected `xml` and solution

Answer (score 2):

You should be registering your XML namespace with:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('api', 'http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API');
```

not

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('api', 'http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API');
```

The response comes back with:

```
<get_cdrsResponse xmlns="http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API">
```

It does not matter if this URL is resolvable or not, it only matters that the strings match up.

Answer (score 1):

When I replace your line

`if ($xpath->query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/api:get_cdrsResponse')->length < 1)`

with:

`if ($xpath->query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/get_cdrsResponse')->length < 1)`

and remove the 'xmlns' part from get_cdrsResponse it works. So the problem is in the `api:` part..I noticed the xmlns in get_cdrsResponse returns a 404 (http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API), so I'd suggest to begin fixing that.

Comment: you're right but that happand cause the response XML was so big so i decided to delete most if it so it'll be readable. anyway theres a matching close tag. (look again on the code above). what am I doing wrong in my PHP code?

Comment: Now that you have the complete code I'll try and debug it for you!

Comment: Ok my solution is not working..but the xmlns isn't found: http://www.flatplanetphone.net/Integrics/Enswitch/API ...maybe that's got something to do with it?